# Keep query order results view as entered in the sql view using Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

How do I keep the query order results as in the sql view the same. I use the following sql to obtain the results

```
SELECT TableName.NumBR
FROM TableName
WHERE 
NumBR = ""
OR NumBR Like "3101"
OR NumBR Like "3541"
OR NumBR Like "4381"
OR NumBR Like "AS3281"
OR NumBR Like "4260"
OR NumBR Like "4315"
OR NumBR Like "4330"
OR NumBR Like "4382"
OR NumBR Like "9410"
OR NumBR Like "9570"
OR NumBR Like "AS3710"
OR NumBR Like "AS4450"
OR NumBR Like "K400"
OR NumBR Like "3100"
OR NumBR Like "3130"
OR NumBR Like "3280"
OR NumBR Like "3495"
OR NumBR Like "3540"
OR NumBR Like "3610"
OR NumBR Like "3700"
OR NumBR Like "4110"
OR NumBR Like "4200";
```

but the results are always resorted in ascending order when I would like the order to remain as entered in the sql view.

Comment: Thank you Microsoft, but you can't.  It's a "feature".

Comment: @SableFoste Show me an example that works with any database Microsoft or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not selected an order, you have created a where statement. You can use a temporary table with an autonumber for your criteria, then you can use the autonumber for your order.

```
SELECT TableName.NumBR
FROM TableName
INNER JOIN temp 
ON TableName.NumBR = Temp.NumBR
ORDER BY Temp.ID
```

Comment: but there are more than one occurrence of the records being selected so I wanted all of the ones that pertain to above numbers. Does this still work?

Comment: Yes, it does work. The only problem may be with the autonumber losing the sequence, but that is easily enough fixed with a temporary table, and very rare anyway.

Comment: the process i did was recreate the table and allowed Access to create an autoid then I ran two queries. Once to select the records and then one to apply the order. But I went from 679 records to double the amount of records in the complete table. Which cannot be correct.

Comment: You should only have a single value in the temp table for each value you require.

Comment: there is only one ID for each of the NumBR from the temp that I am selecting but the results have are no where near what I had just by using the sql I used in the first place.

Comment: You have no duplicated NumBR in the temp table but you are getting too many results, is that correct?

Comment: the NumBR field does have duplicates but the ID field does not.

Comment: You must not have duplicates. The ID is irrelevant except for sorting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15275/discussion-between-capnhud-and-remou)