# Correct syntax for adding an expression to a query in Access 2007 (

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I came across this [How Do I Sequentially Number Records in an Access Query](http://www.ehow.com/how_5976723_do-number-records-access-query_.html)
in order to do what I was trying to do based on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935615/keep-query-order-results-view-as-entered-in-the-sql-view-using-access-2007/11935712#11935712) I posted (which I never got to do what I was after) but each time that I try to add the AS Counter to the query I get

```
The expression you entered contains invalid syntax
You may have entered an operand without an operator
```

using the following sql:

```
SELECT Maintable.NumBR, Maintable.*, [Ehow] AS Expr1
FROM Maintable
WHERE (((Maintable.[NumBR])="" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3101" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3541" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4381" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "AS3281" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4260" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4315" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4330" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4382" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "9410" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "9570" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "AS3710" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "AS4450" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "K400" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3100" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3130" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3280" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3495" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3540" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3610" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "3700" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4110" 
  Or (Maintable.[NumBR]) Like "4200")

AND (([Ehow])=DCount("[NumBR]","[Maintable]"," [NumBR] <= " & [NumBR])));
```

**EDIT** the question posed in the previous stackoverflow question answers this question.

Comment: What did you not understand about the sample database I uploaded? You should post sample data and an example of what you want returned.

Comment: I could see the you had a id that duplicated when it should have, but I could not see how the id was even added to records found. Or how to select and then add an ID

Comment: Did you look at the query sql?

Comment: I see the maintable which is in the correct format, and then I see the temptable which has the same field as the maintable with the addition of an id. How is the temptable to be created based on only returning the NumBR records I want. There are more than just those that were in the list which will need to not be returned in the query

Comment: Are you asking how the records get into the temp table?

Comment: yes specifically just the ones in the list while filtering through all the rest

Comment: How did the Numbr list get into the where statement above?

Comment: it came from selecting certain numbers from the NumBR field using the where statement

Comment: How did you select them? Did you type them? Copy them from a control? How did you get the list?

Comment: that list is selected by me and then entered into the sql. I was wanting the ability to say I only want the following records (the list), and additionally I want them to stay in the order in which I wanted them

Comment: So type the list into the temp table in the order that you want them. Delete any you do not want. Run the sample query.

Comment: that is it. I see  was not completely understanding what you said. additionally I see you have allow duplicates in the NumBR field mine was set differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *AS Counter* phrase is not needed in your query.  In the linked example, that's added to the *SELECT* statement to alias the column; in your example you're working with the *WHERE* clause, so that *AS* phrase wouldn't do anything (and is actually invalid).

Comment: That is exactly what I said in the previous question, a long discussion and a sample database. I wonder if your restatement will help.